# SQL beginner - How do I retrieve the youngest patient that tested positive?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm creating code that simulates patients going to the hospital to test for covid-19. I need to consult the youngest patient that tested positive (the patients only have different ages), but I can't get the information right about the patient (`patient_name`, `codepatient`). I've tried using subquery:

```sql
SELECT P.patient_name, P.patient_age, T.results
FROM patient P
    LEFT OUTER JOIN testing T on T.codepatient=P.codepatient
WHERE P.patient_age = 
      (SELECT min(P.patient_age)
      FROM patient P);
```

But I can't find a way to retrieve the testing = 'Positive'. I also tried this:

```sql
SELECT P.patient_name, min(P.patient_age), T.results, T.codepatient
FROM patient P
  INNER JOIN testing T on T.codepatient=P.codepatient
WHERE T.results = 'Positive';
```

Unfortunately it shows only the right age, the name and code are selected from the oldest patient.
I'm a college student and I'm beginning to use MySQL. English is my second language, i'm trying my best to ask this question clearly, i apologize if i make mistakes.

Comment: What result to do you expect if two people have the youngest age?

Comment: Since I made the code i only used different ages. The discipline is "introduction to database", we are learning the basics on MySQL.

Comment: @gibby - I hope [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65359381/10819573) resolved your problem. If yes, you can help the community by marking the answer as accepted. An accepted answer helps future visitors use the solution confidently. Feel free to comment below the answer in case of any doubt/issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include the test for `Positive` in the subselect:

```
SELECT p.patient_name, p.patient_age, t.results
  FROM patient p
  INNER JOIN testing t
    on t.codepatient = p.codepatient
  WHERE p.patient_age = (SELECT min(p.patient_age)
                           FROM patient p
                           INNER JOIN testing t
                             ON t.codepatient = p.codepatient
                           WHERE t.results = 'Positive');
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=311ee7f19e84e94d5186d5687ac643c8)

Answer (score 0):

You need to order the data by age, then use LIMIT 1 to get one record

```
SELECT P.pacient_name, P.pacient_age, T.results, T.codepacient
FROM pacient P
  INNER JOIN testing T on T.codepacient=P.codepacient
WHERE T.results = 'Positive' ORDER BY p.pacient_age LIMIT 1
```

Comment: It didn't work :(, i was wondering if maybe i need to use an outer join... Oh well. I really am trying my best, i've done pretty much everything i thought might work.

Comment: The result was the same as the one I was getting before: it only retrieved the age correctly. The name and patient code are wrong, it shows the name and patient code of the oldest patient instead of youngest.